# Old subpanel on boathouse

Tags: subpanel

You are going to tell me to call a licensed electrician but someone needs to tell me how to find one. I am all about qualified electricians, but my last 2 experiences with a licensed electricians were a joke.  I knew more code than they did.  They were glorified wire pullers.  I will hire one to do the actual work, but I need to make sure they are doing it right.

Issue:
I have an old boathouse with a 240v subpanel supplied by an 8/3 with no ground (black, red, white only) with a 30a 2pole breaker in the main breaker.  It is about 75 feet from the main breaker.  The wire runs underground through what seems to be old plastic water pipe.

The loads I have at the boathouse are:
*LED lights
*Small mini-Fridge
*2ea 120v boat lifts (which will never be used at the same time - I probably will wire them to prevent them from being used as the same time)

I am replacing the subpanel, but trying to figure out the best way to get a ground.   Regardless, I know I will have to put in Ground rods as there are none there currently.  The options as I see it:

1. Make it a 120v breaker.  Not a bad choice, but I do like the two hots to reduce amps on a single circuit. But with no 240v loads, how is it helping as it still has a 8ga neutral? If I did this, which color wire should be the Ground - the red one?  How do I mark it as ground?
2. Run a #6 bare ground from the main to grounding rods, then finish at the new subpanel. ( I think a separate ground outside the sheathing is allowed by code, right?)  I was going to use something like cable burying equipment to keep from digging up the yard.

Problem is while it is a straight shot and level, I have to go over a drive way, go over city water line, field lines, and the actual 8/3.  I am not sure 811 will be able to find them all.  I am assuming I wouldn't have to bury this very deep.

3. Run new 4 wire UF to the boat house, but beside problems as seen in #2, I would have to dig a ditch so I can put in marker for the wire.
4. Transformer - (I am kinda liking this solution) The problem is I know nothing about a transformer.  Can I feed it with 8/3 currently at the boathouse and then feed my new panel off the transformer (which will now be a Main). If I go to this option, what kind of transformer do I buy?
5. GFCI - Just spoke with a licensed electrician and he said just put in GFCI plugs.  Would this be an option?  How about just GFCI breakers to protect plugs as well as lighting?

Thoughts?

---

Additional commentary:

Detached sub panel - correct on not bonded. Current code must have 4 wires to 240v subpanel. You need a way for the power to get back to the source if neutral fails.

Distance from shore-15 feet.

White wire- correct, all I have is neutral and no ground.

Diameter of water pipe is 3/4”. It is fairly tight. I thought of snaking a wire, but…

Comment: I think with a detached building, you do need to have ground rod/s, so a ground wire to rod/s from sub panel should be all you need.  With a sub panel neutral and ground must not be bonded together.

Comment: Why would we tell you to get a licensed electrician? We are a DIY forum and we generally reserve that tretament for those who demonstrate by their words that they are too impulsive and irresponsible to be trusted with electrical work.  While the jury is still out on that, the jury is certainly back on whether the last guy was.  Holy smoke, it couldn't have been made worse for [electric shock drownings](https://www.electricshockdrowning.org)!!!!  I hope there's a 40A GFCI breaker at the house end of that cable, at least!   Nah, we can fix this.

Comment: How close is this subpanel to the shoreline?

Comment: You HAVE a neutral - white wire in the feed. What you don't have, and need, is a ground.

Comment: Also, what diameter is said "water pipe"?

Comment: Other questions about the loads: how many square feet is the boathouse, and how many HP are the boat lifts?

Comment: For that matter, what's the make and model of the existing subpanel?

Comment: A quick search find conduit fill for PVC 40 = 8 AWG x 5, PVC 80 = 8 AWG x 4. So you *should* be able to get a ground through the existing conduit.

Comment: Please register your account by tying it to an email/password, Google, Facebook etc.   Then hit "flag"... "moderator attention" and type in "please merge my accounts".

Comment: Here are the [instructions on merging two accounts](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 1):

[Electric shock drowning](https://www.electricshockdrowning.org/) is very serious business. The previous work suggests shocking ignorance from the last installer, who was keen on barely complying with a very outdated Code edition.

First, turn the circuit off Right Now at the house, and don't turn it back on until problems are cured.  It is absolutely irresponsible to continue the circuit in service as it is now.

Can you fix it yourself? Very likely, especially if you go "belt and suspenders".  And you have a good sense, and your transformer idea is a very good one.

### To get it back in service *in a hurry*

Back at the house there is a 30A or 40A breaker in the main panel that feeds all this mess.  Make sure it is a 2-pole GFCI breaker.  Since they're about $90, spend extra time *making sure* it is the correct breaker type for your panel. Post a pic of your panel (or just details off the label) and we can match you up to the correct breakers.  The hardware store guy will tell you all 1" breakers are interchangeable, **that is wrong**.  The bus shapes are different, and this will cause arcing.

Your wire is actually allowed 40A.  (and possible 50A depending on wire type).

And we're at least in safety-land at this point.  We can re-energize the thing and get it back in service.

### That cable

Since it is a *cable*, the pipe doesn't matter at all. What matters is whether the cable is outdoor-rated, and whether it is under 24" of cover (or 18" if inside **proper** conduit, or 6" if that legal conduit is RMC or IMC).

With older groundless wire you need to read the writing on the side of the cable, but more recently UF will be gray and NM black.

If you find aluminum wire, don't worry. It can be worked with by following 3 simple rules (which were not known in the 1970s).  #8 AL is good for 35A (and often 40A depending on wire type).

Anyway, job 1 is identifying that feeder cable and see *if it's even legal*. If it's NM type, don't even bother buying that GFCI breaker as it will trip due to degradation of NM from being outside.  If it's illegal cable or buried illegally, you'll need to run a new 4-wire feeder.  Consider #6 aluminum (50A) or #2 aluminum (90A).  Nothing wrong with aluminum feeder.

### If the cable is a keeper, how do we "safe" it?

Well, simplest is to use a GFCI breaker, separate neutral and ground at the panel, and then add a *robust* local ground rod system tied to panel ground.  This may result in neutral being a modest voltage away from ground due to voltage gradients, but that's not a big deal since there's a GFCI back at the origin.   The GFCI makes up for a lot of sins.

Your idea of setting it up as a 120V panel is reasonable.  However, using the red wire as a ground is a technically a Code violation.  Since the wire is good for at least 40A, you can probably power everything and don't need to fool around with interlocks on the boat lift.

Retrofitting a ground is also acceptable assuming the existing cable is acceptable. (remember if the pipe isn't legal for conduit, it can't be at conduit-only depths like 6" or 18").

### Transformer

However, your transformer concept also has merit.  Your power would be 9600 VA at 40A (or 12,000 VA at 50A), so you need a transformer of that size.  It needs to be an isolation transformer.  These are commonly sold to knock commercial 480V down to 120/240V split-phase, but can be jumpered for 240V on the primary side. Make sure to get one with an outdoor enclosure.

Since the transformer is isolating, you have a *separately derived service* and your panel will be a main panel where it locally establishes the neutral-ground relationship with its own local ground rods.  This will be much safer, because it ensures that neutral and ground are at *local* earth potential.   Power can still be dangerous, however, so you still need GFCI protection for any receptacle or boat hookup. (so that a mis-wired boat or shore connection doesn't energize the water).